# Passing python objects across interpreters

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to exchange objects between two python interpreters working on the same (and different ) machines.

Is there a mechanism to achieve the same?

~Vijay

**To be more specific:**
I have few processes running on same  (and different) machine(s).  Few of these processes produce objects which are consumed by the other processes. I am trying to tackle a producer/consumer problem among these processes.

I was previously running these processes on the same python interpreter as threads, and was able to use queues to solve the producer-consumer problem. However due to increasing loads I have decided to shift some processes to other machines. Now these processes residing on different machines(and interpreters) need to share the access to a queue. I would like to know if there is a mechanism which helps me do this efficiently.

I could write a single class which manages the queue and handles the objects to/from the other processes using sockets.

I think this is a common problem if one wants to use python to handle large amounts of data.
Hence I was interested to know if there were other more elegant solutions available.

~Vijay

Comment: The first thing you should do is search for ways to serialize Python objects.  The second thing you should do is actually read the Google results you find.  After reading those results, please **update** your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you need to serialize the object. In Python that means pickle and unpickle. You can pickle an object on one side, transfer it somehow (socket, etc.) the other and unpickle it. Use the `pickle` or `cPickle` modules for that.

The [Pyro](http://www.xs4all.nl/~irmen/pyro3/) package is a complete package that does this in a transparent way.

Answer (score 5):

Use the pickle module of Python in order to serialize/deserialize an object state:

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html